# Create table using hibernate based on table's 1 row columns

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, jsoup

I have an HTML document that contains some 95 tables. 
I am using Spring boot, JPA, hibernate, Mysql 8 and Jsoup to parse HTML

Question: Is there a way to create a table/class (dynamically using Elements position i.e. table0 for element.get(0) and have the column name be the same as table heading columns

Example

```
<table border="0" width="600" class="tdiff" summary="This table displays database instance information">
<tr>
 <th class="awrbg" scope="col">DB Name</th>
 <th class="awrbg" scope="col">DB Id</th>
 <th class="awrbg" scope="col">Instance</th>
 <th class="awrbg" scope="col">Inst num</th>
 <th class="awrbg" scope="col">Startup Time</th>
 <th class="awrbg" scope="col">Release</th>
 <th class="awrbg" scope="col">RAC</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td scope="row" class='awrnc'>TESTDB</td>
 <td align="right" class='awrnc'>133123242</td>
 <td class='awrnc'>TESTDB</td>
 <td align="right" class='awrnc'>1</td>
 <td class='awrnc'>21-Oct-19 08:10</td>
 <td class='awrnc'>12.1.0.2.0</td>
 <td class='awrnc'>NO</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

*Create an entity class (dynamically)!*

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table01")
public Class Table01 {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "table01_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "table01_seq_gen", sequenceName = "table01_seq")
    Long id;

    String DBName;
    String DBId;
    String Instance;
    String Instnum;
    String StartupTime;
    String Release;
    String RAC;
}
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: Look at [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#dynamic-model).